# Docker on Ubuntu inside WSL

Tags: docker, ubuntu-18.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I want to play with hyperledger fabric and this require to have linux.
Right now I want to use Windows and my idea was to install Ubuntu with WSL and just develop inside it.
The problem apear when I want to use docker.

I follow the steps in [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@sebagomez/installing-the-docker-client-on-ubuntus-windows-subsystem-for-linux-612b392a44c4) step by step but I run into some problem.

```
filip@CSGN044D:~$ docker --version
Docker version 19.03.5, build 633a0ea838


filip@CSGN044D:~$ docker run hello-world
docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?.
See 'docker run --help'.


filip@CSGN044D:~$ sudo service docker start
 * Starting Docker: docker
```

and again...

```
filip@CSGN044D:~$ docker run hello-world
docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

Is this even possible ?

Comment: Have you tried running as superuser `sudo docker run hello-world`?

Comment: yes, doesn't help

Comment: Try running `DOCKER_HOST=tcp://localhost:2375 docker info` and see if it works

Comment: yea, this work, I left the tutorial in the comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your Docker CLI is still trying to connect to the local Unix socket instead of localhost. Make sure your `DOCKER_HOST` environment variable is set to `tcp://localhost:2375`

Try by setting it in your shell first

```
export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://localhost:2375
```

Sanity check

```
echo $DOCKER_HOST
```

Now try running all your regular Docker commands. If those work, add this to your `.bashrc`

```
echo "export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://localhost:2375" >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

Not that in the tutorial the author uses `localhost:2375` instead of `tcp://localhost:2375`. I think you have to explicitly specify the protocol. Also, your shell might not be using `bash_profile` as the config file (Usually Mac shells use that) so try adding it to your `bashrc` instead.